# Loops for multiple conditional subsets in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set for precipitation in the US that is divided by: state, district (within state), year and month. The record goes back to 1895.

I am trying to extract the 121 year average (1895 - present) for each district within each state by month. Obviously one could do this by splitting and/ or subsetting but I don't wont to rewrite the same basic line of code over and over. What I would like to do is run a loop that will work through the data set by state, district and month rendering the 121 year average for each of the 12 months - ie: alabama, district 01, jan - wyoming, district 10, dec.

Here is the 1st and last lines of the data table:

```
state, district, year, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, June, July, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec
01, 01 1895 7.37 1.41  7.17  2.72 3.06  4.04 4.58 4.00 3.41 2.28 1.83 5.83

...

50, 13, 2016, 4.77, 3.02, 3.28, -9.99, -9.99, -9.99, -9.99, -9.99, -9.99, -9.99, -9.99, -9.99
```

Any suggestion/ help in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing some commas.

Comment: `library(tidyr) ; library(dplyr) ; df %>% gather(month, value, Jan:Dec) %>% group_by(state, district, month) %>% summarise(avg = mean(value))` or base or data.table equivalents

Comment: No loops are needed. A simple aggregate can work: `meandf <- aggregate(.~state + district, sourcedf, FUN = mean)`

Comment: Thanks! The aggregate function is working wonders.

Comment: Okay so aggregate is great, but when I ran a test to see if the 'x' column means were coming out correctly they did not match. Here's my code: >aggregate(subs$Jan, list(state = subs$state, district = subs$district), na.rm = TRUE, mean) -> abc
> head(abc)
  state district        x
1    02       01 1.137295
...
> xyz <- subset(subs, subs$state == "02", subs$district == "01", select = Jan)
> mean(xyz, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1.281464

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var = c('state', 'district', 'year'),
     variable.name= 'month')[, .(avg = mean(value)) ,.(state, district, month)]
```